# Find the extremal point of $x^2 + 2xy + 4y^2 + 6$ and show it is a minimum point by completing the square

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'll admit that my elementary algebra sucks. This winter break I want to work through Algebra: An Elementary Textbook by G. Chrystal. The question at hand is confusing me; I hope someone can walk me through it.

Comment: What do you get when you complete the square?

Comment: Have you found the extremal point via calculus? If yes, what is it? If no, do it and show your work.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not showing the calculus part as that's direct calculation.
The minimum occurs at $ x = 0, y = 0 $, and has value 6.

---

In terms of completing the square, we have

> $$ (x+y)^2 + 3y^2 + 6 $$

Hence, the minimum is 6.

Another way of completing the square is

> $$ (2y + \frac{x}{2} ) ^2 + \frac{3}{4} x^2 + 6 $$

Again, the minimum is 6.

Comment: That's not very **good** way of completing the square!

Comment: Sorry, that was a foolish mistake and I thought I had deleted it!

Answer (score 1):

Let $$x^2+2xy+4y^2+6=z$$, see it as quadratic of $y$, treat $x,z$ as constants. Find $y$:

$$y=\frac{-2x\pm \sqrt{4x^2-16(x^2+6-z)}}{8}$$ For $y$ to be real $$-12x^2-96+16z\ge 0 \implies 16z-96>12x^2 \ge 0 \implies 16z\ge 96 \implies z\ge 6.$$ The minimum of $z$ equal to 6 occurs when $x=y=0$.

One may also write $$z=(x+y)^2+3y^2+6 \implies z \ge 6$$